# How is the __len__ method implemented in various container types in Python?

Tags: python

Until now, when I used the `len` function with various container types (let's say the `list` type for now), I assumed that each container type has a *field* member which stores the length of that particular object.. Coming from Java, this made a lot of sense. But when I come to think about it, I don't think this is true, this made me confused.

Whenever I'm using the `len` function on an object which implement `__length__`, does it calculates the length by iterating on the object's elements, or just returning the length somehow immediately?

The question came to me actually from using the `dict` built-in type. I added some elements (a lot of them) to the dictionary and eventually I needed to get the amount of elements in the dictionary, so because I'm not sure what is the time complexity of the `len` function, I decided to count the elements as I insert them... but I'm not sure this is the right solution to my problem.

This is an example code for my question:

```
d = {}
count = 0
for i in range(10 ** 6):
    d[i] = True
    count += 1
```

VS

```
d = {i: True for i in range(10 ** 6)}
count = len(d)
```

Second solution looks nicer (and shorter) to me... and I know that theoretically the time complexity is the same whether the `len` function is instant or not, in the second solution I'm afraid it iterates twice to 10 ** 6 (first for the dictionary comprehension, and second for the length calculation).

Enlighten me please.

Comment: AFAIK all built-ins(and standard library types) provide `O(1)` `__len__` implementations. Even `deque` which is a doubly-linked list. However for custom types the `__len__` can have different complexity. Anyway you *should* always use it, because *using `len` conveys the meaning of what you want to do*, while other solutions are much less readable and with any reasonable type they are even slower/equal in speed.

Comment: I actually made a search but I probably didn't search for the right terms. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 10):

You are very definitely over-thinking this. Python is not really the language that you should be using if you're worried about optimising at this level.

That said, on the whole Python's containers *do* know their own lengths, without having to iterate. The built-in types are implemented in C (in the CPython implementation), and I'd have to dig into the actual code to find out exactly where it's implemented, but `len` is always a constant-time call.

Comment: If I happen to use the `len` function a lot in the same code on the same object, this "optimization thinking" is justified. Usually I would just use a variable to store that length, but let's say I have a function which populates an empty dictionary, and in the end it returns that dictionary, if the complexity of `len` would be O(n), I would return the length of the dictionary from that function as well (if the length is needed), but if not and it's O(1) as said, I wouldn't and just use `len` on it when necessary.